# jQuery: Adding a class to an element when it contains an image, but only if there are no text nodes

Tags: jquery

I want jQuery to add a `class` of `diog-fail` to an `<a>` when it contains an `<img />` but does not contain a string of text, or another HTML element that contains a string of text. The 2 examples below would be false:

```
<a href="#">
    <img width="100" height="100" alt="alternative text" src="some/location/image.gif" />
    Some text
</a>

<a href="#">
    <img width="100" height="100" alt="alternative text" src="some/location/image.gif" />
    <span>Some text</span>
</a>
```

The following example would have jQuery apply the `class` of `diog-fail`:

```
<a href="#">
    <img width="100" height="100" alt="alternative text" src="some/location/image.gif" />
</a>
```

**Important:** The string of text could be anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use `.text()` to grab out a concatenation of all the text in the anchor (ignoring markup). You can then `$.trim` it and test the length. Add the `.diog-fail` class to elements with zero-length `.text()`:

```
$("a:has(img)").filter(function() {
   return !$.trim($(this).text()).length; 
}).addClass("diog-fail");
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/Pd56p/2/)

Comment: Nice and concise - my solution ran to 6 lines.